# Does KeepAliveTime still work in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keep-alive

Does is still work, or have any effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft from Vista onward the following registry key exists:

KeepAliveTime
Key: Tcpip\Parameters
Value Type: REG_DWORD—time in milliseconds
Valid Range: 0–0xFFFFFFFE
Default: 7,200,000 (two hours)
Description: This value controls how often TCP attempts to verify that an idle connection is still intact by sending a keep-alive packet. If the remote system is still reachable and functioning, it acknowledges the keep-alive transmission. Keep-alive packets are not sent by default. This feature may be enabled on a connection by an application.

There is also this [Technet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives.aspx) called 'Things that you may want to know about TCP Keepalives' that discusses it further.